# How to provide a custom broker.xml to ActiveMQ Artemis broker instance

Tags: activemq-artemis

How can I provide a custom `broker.xml` to my instance of ActiveMQ Artemis? The standard implementation generates the config data in the broker instance's `etc` directory but I wish to mount my own config files.

Comment: Can you not simply copy your own files to the broker instance's `etc` directory to replace the ones that are already there?

Comment: Justin... The broker is created in a deployment (script running in docker file)... Configs are mounted in deployment but broker has not yet been created so no directory structure to mount into

Comment: I will try to copy from volume mount after broker is created... Inside same script

Comment: So is your use-case specific to docker?

Comment: Yes... I can volume mount and copy the volume file after the broker instance is created.. That works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're starting the broker with the `artemis run` command then you can pass the location of a custom `bootstrap.xml`, e.g.:

```
$ ./artemis run xml:/path/to/myBootstrap.xml
```

The `bootstrap.xml` will then indicate where to find a custom `broker.xml`.

You can also use `--broker` to override the location of `broker.xml` read from `bootstrap.xml`, e.g.:

```
$ ./artemis run --broker /path/to/myBroker.xml
```

Comment: Hi Justin..the artemis run does not accept --configuration ..would you have an example of how to pass in the bootstrap.xml ? I get configuration error when I try to copy the bootstrap.xml into the broker

Comment: You're right. I read the code wrong when I first looked at it. I updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Justin ..when i try to pass in a bootstrap.xml i get an error... Cannot find the declaration of element 'configuration'.

Comment: If i use the same bootstrap.xml as the broker creates i still get the same error ...

Comment: The `<configuration>` element is part of a normal `broker.xml`. If you're getting an XML parsing error about the absence of `<configuration>` then the `broker.xml` you're using is malformed.

Comment: The broker.xml works when I do not try to put my own bootstrap.xml

Comment: I recommend you create a new question where you can fully explain exactly what you're doing and exactly what error you're receiving. At this point I'm not sure what's actually happening.